# paper-input used with an if template

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I have some content that I want to show `if` the user checks a `paper-checkbox`.

I thought I used to (prior to 1.0) be able to do something along the lines of

```
<template is='auto-binding'>
    <paper-checkbox checked="{{isChecked}}"></paper-checkbox>
    <template if='{{isChecked}}'>
        Conditional content
    </template>
</template>
```

But that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-binding and conditional templates have [changed in Polymer v1.0+](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html).

- Auto-binding templates now use `is="dom-bind"`.
- Conditional templates now use `is="dom-if"` as well as the `if` attribute.

```html
<template is="dom-bind">
  <paper-checkbox checked="{{isChecked}}"></paper-checkbox>
  <template is="dom-if" if="{{isChecked}}">
    Conditional content
  </template>
</template>
```